# How to disable emoticons in HTML fields?

Tags: php, jquery, html, symfony, emoticons

On my symfony2 application, I have a form and a textarea in this form. So when I try the form on my Xperia Z3 I can choose some emoticons and add them to the fields.

When I submit the form and debug the form content in my textarea field I got something like that :

```
ðŸ˜�ðŸ˜‚ðŸ˜ŠðŸ˜±ðŸ�”ðŸ˜¨ðŸ�”ðŸ˜¨ðŸ˜�ðŸ˜‚ðŸ˜®ðŸ
```

So, my question is :

- Can we disable all emoticons on each cellphone (Android, IOS, WP...) keyboard ?
- Or there is a way to remove/replace this content in my controller ?

Thanks

Comment: You could try to `preg_replace` everything besides some allowed characters like letters, numbers, punctuation, whitespace etc.

Comment: `<form  accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">` ?

Comment: Yes Reeno i will `preg_replace` everythings except letters, numbers, spaces, accents... But there is a way to remove specials characters like `ðŸ˜ŠðŸ˜±ðŸ`and keep accents ? For exemple can I replace `ðŸ˜®ðŸ My adress is érodBô çaté @# ðŸ˜ŠðŸ˜±ðŸ my text`into `My adress is érodBô çaté @#  my text` ?? Thanks